# How to accurately check for cause of plagiarism for programming assignments with online content

Tags: computer-science, university, plagiarism, code

I heard that most of the code plagiarism checkers use MOSS for evaluation. But MOSS doesn't check for any content in GitHub or present on the internet. How do we exactly tackle the problem of checking the whole code present on the internet (eg GitHub public repos, Kaggle public notebooks, etc). If let's say we had a similar assignment from the previous years and some students just tweaked the assignment to get it done. We can have the submissions from the previous years while we send them to moss but that does not solve the problem as they are not exactly similar but with a few minor tweaks.